# Laravel Eloquent, how do I start listing data from the middle of a result set?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table (model name: Data):

```
Id  Data1  Data2
1   A      ...
2   B      ...
3   C      ...
...
...
...
24  X      ...
25  Y      ...
26  Z      ...
```

And a query in Eloquent to retrieve the data:

```
$datum = Data::orderBy("data1")->paginate(10);
```

Right now the query always starts at the top with "A" and goes through all 3 pages to "Z", which is fine when the user initially hits the screen.  If the user edits id=15 data1="o", how do I restart the list At id 15 or page 2 instead of going back to the top of the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fourth parameter

```
$datum = Data::orderBy("data1")->paginate(10, ['*'], 'page', 2);
```

2 - page number

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [skip/take Laravel methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset):

**Quick answer:**

```
$count = 26; 
$skip = 15;
$limit = $count - $skip;
$datum = Data::orderBy("data1")->skip($skip)->take($limit)->get();
```

---

**Explanation:**

**1)** First, count the rows:

```
$count = Data::count(); 
// OR
$count = 26; // In your case (alphabet letters) you can set $count directly to 26
```

**2)** Then set a number of rows to skip (*or get it from the query parameters, so users can edit a form*)

```
$skip = 15;
// OR
$skip = $request->input('id'); // get it from a query parameter set by the user
```

**3)** Calculate the amount of rows remaining (*all the ones that you are going to fetch*)

```
$limit = $count - $skip;
```

**4)** Finally, collect the data, skipping the 15 first ones

```
$datum = Data::orderBy("data1")->skip($skip)->take($limit)->get(); 
// be aware that you can not paginate when using skip/take
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) you can use `page` query string in your URL to point on a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Dry7, Giorgio.dev and PhilMarc.  You all gave me a piece of the answer.  The final solution is going to be a lot more complex.  This is due to changes to the page calculation because of sort order for the table (any of four columns) and how many records I’m filtering out (any of three columns).  In addition to clearing the filter if a new or edited record falls outside the filter.  The latest copy of the table and my code (which let me keep the paging provided by Laravel) is as follows;

```
mysql> show columns from mailing_classes;
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| mailing_class_code | char(2)             | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description        | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_by_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_editted_by_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at         | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at         | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

public function index()
{

    $mailingClassSortOrder = session('mailingClassSortOrder');
    $mailingClassRestartValue = session('mailingClassRestartValue');
    $mailingClassSearchLeft = session('mailingClassSearchLeft');
    $mailingClassSearchRight = session('mailingClassSearchRight');
    $rows = 1;
    $page = 0;
    $restart = 0;
    $mcCode = '';
    $mcDescription = '';
    $mcUpdatedAt = '';

    if ($mailingClassRestartValue > 0) {
        $restartRows = MailingClass::where('id', '=', $mailingClassRestartValue)->get();
        foreach ($restartRows as $restartRow) {
            $mcCode = $restartRow->mailing_class_code;
            $mcDescription = $restartRow->description;
        }
        // if restart value does not appear in the filter then clear the filter
        // {deleted for sake of space}
        // find row position based on sort order
        if ($mailingClassSortOrder === "mailing_class_code") {
            // sorted by mailing_class_code column
            $rows = MailingClass::where('mailing_class_code', '<=', $restartRow->mailing_class_code)->count();
        } elseif ($mailingClassSortOrder === "id") {
            // sorted by id column
            $rows = MailingClass::where('id', '<=', $restartRow->id)->count();
        } elseif ($mailingClassSortOrder === "description") {
            // sorted by description column
            $rows = MailingClass::where('description', '<=', $restartRow->description)->count();
        } elseif ($mailingClassSortOrder === "updated_at") {
            // sorted by updated_at column
            $rows = MailingClass::where('updated_at', '<=', $restartRow->updated_at)->count();
        }
    }
    // calculate what should be the current page
    $page = intval($rows / 10) + 1;

    $searchText = '';
    $mailingClasses = [];
    if ($mailingClassSearchLeft === '') {
        if ($mailingClassRestartValue <= 0) {
            $mailingClasses = MailingClass::orderBy($mailingClassSortOrder)->paginate(10);
        } else {
            $mailingClasses = MailingClass::orderBy($mailingClassSortOrder)->paginate(10, ['*'], 'page', $page);
        }

    } elseif ($mailingClassSearchLeft === 'id') {
        // {deleted for sake of space}
    } elseif ($mailingClassSearchLeft === 'mailing_class_code') {
        // {deleted for sake of space}
    } elseif (session('mailingClassSearchLeft') === 'mailing_class_description') {
        // {deleted for sake of space}
    } else {
        // {deleted for sake of space}
    }

    return view(
        'maintenance.mailingclass.index',
        compact('mailingClasses', 'mmsGlobal', 'searchText')
    );
}
```

I took out a lot of code that had to do with creating filters to try and make it as concise.  Hope I didn’t delete too much.  Now the question is how do I optimize it.